# Styling ionic2 radio buttons fail

Tags: html, css, radio-button, ionic2

I have some radio buttons but the text appear far away from the radio button and i would like to have the text eing closer to the radio button

This is my code

```
ion-row radio-group (ionChange)="onChange($event)">
     <ion-col width-30>
       <ion-item>
           <ion-label>Yes</ion-label>
           <ion-radio value='{{checklists.controls["yesradio"].value}}-yes'>  </ion-radio>
       </ion-item>
     </ion-col>


     <ion-col width-30>

         <ion-item  style="text-align:left">
             <ion-label>No</ion-label>
              <ion-radio style="margin:0px;"  value='{{checklists.controls["yesradio"].value}}-no'></ion-radio>

       </ion-item>

     </ion-col>

 </ion-row>
```

The above generates
[image]

As from the above picture the yes text is far to the left from the yes radio

Am looking forward to have

[image]

Ive also tried adding

```
  <ion-col width-30>

         <ion-item  style="text-align:left">
             <ion-label style="margin:0px;">No</ion-label>
              <ion-radio style="margin:0px;" id="no_radio"></ion-radio>  //added margin 0px fails

       </ion-item>

     </ion-col>
```

What do i need to add more to bring the icon closer to the text(yes and no) not necessarily with the icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.scss` file of your page, you can do below to achieve desired results.

```
.input-wrapper{
     flex: initial;
}
```